# Endpoint access depending on user affiliation

Tags: .net, rest, security, authorization, endpoint

I've prepared an example diagram to clarify my thoughts.
[Example diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pldqt.png)

I'm wondering how to secure documents endpoint depending on user affilation to specific Department.
What I'm trying to do is secure endpoint in way that user will have access only to documents  that are assigned to specific department if he belongs to this department.

The example I have presented is trivial and I could just refer to PersonDepartment from Document and check if the user who is trying to access the document belongs to a specific department, but what if the Document table is more nested? I'd have to go through all the tables to PersonDepartment and that seems more complicated and I don't know if that makes sense. Is there a better solution?

I would like to implement this using the .Net Core with REST API

Comment: Hi, You can try given every user a unique key i.e uuid, and for every document that belongs to the user should be assigned the user key, requests to fetch any document, you check if keys from sender matches the documents expected key, reject request if unmatched

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. What if structure of database is more complicated and occurs more relations between tables e.g. there is a relation to the contract from the department table, and then do I have to create separate associative tables for the Contract and Document for the Person table? And if some tables were added by analogy, then I would have to combine each of them with a person? More than one user can access a document and only if it is in the department to which the document or contract is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

The diagram can be seen in two seperate parts:

1. Authorization data: `Person` -> `PersonDepartment` -> `Department`
2. Resource data: `Department` -> `DepartmentDocument` -> `Document`

A solution could be to specify the resource data in your URL as much as possible, while the authorization data can then be checked in authorization filter(s).

Assuming that the data is being retrieved from an API, the URL could look like the following:
`[Route("/api/v1/departments/{departmentId}/documents/{documentId}")]`
`https://localhost/api/v1/departments/23/documents/100`

At this point, the variables `department=23` and `document=100` can then be used together to retrieve the desired document. It is important to use all the available resource values together to prevent spoofing on ids.

The query behind this method, for example, could be:

```
SELECT
    [D].[Id],
    [D].[Name]
FROM [Document] AS [D]
JOIN [DepartmentDocument] AS [DD] ON [DD].[DocumentId] = [D].[Id]
WHERE [DD].[DepartmentId] = @DepartmentId AND [D].[Id] = @DocumentId
```

Thats sums up the part for accessing the resource data; accessing hierarchical data can be streamlined by passing the required (hierarchical) values.

For the authorization, you could use an `AuthorizationFilter`, e.g.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace Api
{
    public class DepartmentAuthorizationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            HttpContext httpContext = context.HttpContext;

            if (!httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                context.Result = new ForbidResult();
                return;
            }

            // Retrieve the UserId
            Claim userIdClaim = httpContext.User.Claims.Single(x => x.Type == "id");
            int userId = int.Parse(userIdClaim.Value);

            // Retrieve the requested department
            int departmentId = int.Parse(httpContext.Request.RouteValues["departmentId"].ToString());

            if (!CanAccessDepartment(userId, departmentId))
            {
                context.Result = new ForbidResult();
                return;
            }
        }

        private bool CanAccessDepartment(int userId, int departmentId)
        {
            // Do required checks
        }
    }
}
```

This filter can then be added above Actions and Controllers with
`[TypeFilter(typeof(DepartmentAuthorizationFilter))]`
or you can even register it globally in the Startup if you'd like.

In this case, the query behind the person/department-check looks quite familiar:

```
SELECT
    [P].[Id]
FROM [Person] AS [P]
JOIN [PersonDepartment] AS [PD] ON [PD].[PersonId] = [P].[Id]
WHERE [P].[Id] = @PersonId AND [PD].[DepartmentId] = @DepartmentId
```

Having the retrieval and authorization to resources seperated has alot of advantages. Imagine implementing a permission-based access protocol to determine if a person may open/edit/delete a document. With authorization filters this can be easily implemented.